# Consume multiple WCF services from one client

Tags: wcf

I have web farm with 10 servers running IIS, on every one of them I have the same web site together with the same WCF service (which expose some functionality for reading/deleting cache, sessions, application variables, other internal data)

On some other web server I have an “administration” web application which is a client to the WCF services described above.

What is the best way to create and manage proxy for this kind of architecture?

What is the recommended way to consume the WCF services from the web farm servers in a way it does not require to recompile the client application if new server with WCF service is available?

Can you point me to some resources where is shown some similar setup?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If the service is the same on multiple servers then it's easy, simply provide the endpoint address when opening the connection;

```
MyHelloServiceClient proxy = new MyHelloServiceClient("myServerNameorIP");
```

There is an optional parameter in the constructor for the proxy (assuming you're using proxy generation) which takes a server name, or an EndpointAddress.

Then all you need to have is a list of servers somewhere which you can choose from.