# .Net 4.5 WCF Error 404.3 on IIS 7.5

Tags: wcf, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I deployed a MVC4 web application including a wcf service.
when i try to browse to the .svc file i receive Error 404.3 (Error Code 0x80070032).

I tried all the relevant answers i read:
1. adding a .svc mime
2. checking that the server's ISAPI filter include ASP.Net 4 bothe 32bit and 64bit.
3. checking that Server Managers Features include WCF Activation.

I already have a MVC3 web application with WCF service running on the same server.

Can you please point me to what can cause this problem?

I noticed that on IIS Manager in Handler Mapping there is a difference between the two domains running the applications. the working one is almost empty (include only StaticFile) while the new one has a long list of handlers enabled (I don't know if it is relevant or not).

Thank You!

Answer (score 7):

I had to tick "HTTP Activation" in "Add Role Services" within Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Run command aspnet_regiis -iru in command prompt as an admin and try again.

Comment: where should i run the command? It is not known in command prompt when I run from the start menu.

Comment: Try running it on developer prompt or a normal command prompt after navigating to the directory : %SystemDrive%:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the two WCF services are not running on the same port -- that is, you are not connecting to the MVC3 WCF service. See [How to consume multiple WCF services from one client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686112/how-to-consume-multiple-wcf-services-from-one-client) for how to do this.

Comment: I don't think that one client is the case. these are two seperate applications, on different domains on different app_pools. is the fact that i call the services from different domain don't solve the issue of different endpoints?